# Rails join single record to scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

Lets say there is a model called Comments. No we do `@comments = Comment.where(name: 'John')`. Next we do `comment = Comment.find_or_create_by(...)`. Is there a way in Rails to join `comment` to `@comments`? For arrays I can do `@comments << comment` but I want activeRecords...

`@comments.inspect` returns `"#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>"`

I'm using rails 5.1.3

Thanks, Andreas

Comment: don't you mean `@comments.inspect` returns `"#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>"`?

Comment: You are right, thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try before asking!

Active Record Relations have every method that arrays do available to them, so all you need to do is:

```
@comments << comment
```

or

```
@comments.push(comment)
```

EDIT: Have tried the above and seems to work for me however another solution:

```
ids = @comments.collect(&:id)
@comments = Comment.where(id: (ids + comment.id))
```

This will take the ID's from every record in @comments, then add them to the other comment's ID, then return all comments that have an ID in that range

Comment: Of course I did try before I asked. When I use '<<' I get: undefined method `<<' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: I've just done this in console and it works, what version of ruby are you using?

Comment: what does `@comments.inspect` return?

Comment: Have added another workaround but as @Andy points out  your comments instance variable probably isn't what you think it is

Comment: By using the above solution it will @comments << comment  only return the data in the array form

Comment: In that case use my second approach, I edited my answer

Comment: @kernification I'll need a link to the repo with instructions for how to reproduce to debug this futher

Answer (score 0):

`@comments` will be an array of instances of `Comment`. `comment` will be an instance of `Comment`. Therefore, there is nothing wrong with doing `@comments << comment` and it will achieve the result you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like this
If you want data in the active record format.

```
Comment.where(conditions).or(Comment.where(id: 1))
```

The rest of all the solution are complex or provides the data in the array form.